# .NET types wrongly exposed in VBA

Tags: .net, vba, com, interop

I am trying to understand this weird behaviour in VBA. I have two .NET classes, which inherit interfaces and exposed to COM. I register for COM interop and in VBA I encounter this weird behaviour where the objects show types from incorrect interface. Well explained in code as below:

C# Class:

```cs
namespace ComTest
{
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITestClass))]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class TestClass : ITestClass
    {
        public string TestMethod()
        {
            return "Version 2-PROD Version";
        }
    }

    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITestTrade))]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class TestTrade : ITestTrade
    {
        public string TradeName { get; set; }
        public int QuantityNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In Excel VBA:

```vb
Dim objTestClass As ComTest.TestClass
Set objTestClass = New ComTest.TestClass
Dim str As String
objTestClass. ---> I GET ITestTrade methods in objTestClass

Dim tTestTrade As ComTest.TestTrade
Set tTestTrade = New ComTest.TestTrade
tTestTrade. -----> I GET ITestClass methods in tTestTrade
```

But, if I remove 'ComTest' and simply use the class names, this works fine. i.e,

```vb
Dim objTestClass As TestClass
Set objTestClass = New TestClass
Dim str As String
objTestClass. ---> I GET ITestClass types

Dim tTestTrade As TestTrade
Set tTestTrade = New TestTrade
tTestTrade. -----> I GET ITestTrade
```

Can someone please help me understand this.

Comment: This must be a bug in the VBA editor.  You have a workaround.

Comment: Dont think so. Is this something you replicated and found to be fine because it is happening for me in my other class interface as well. I suspect the tlbs not getting generated with proper interface types.

Comment: I had the same problem recently. It must be something with registration. I had to change all guids (literally all) + guid on assembly. After some period, the problem was back, and again changing all guids helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find exact reason as to why it happened. But apparently something had gone wrong in my tlb registration and the way in which I had my types exposed to COM. This might help for someone if you had similar issues:

I was able to stop it by:

- Having a assembly guid attribute for the assembly. (in the assemblyinfo.cs)
- Specifically mentioning the GUID attribute for every class and exposes interfaces.
- And using the below way to expose the .Net classes

  ```cs
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IEvfExternalClient))]
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  public class EvfExternalClient : IEvfExternalClient
  {
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you experience this problem, definitely create a unique GUID for each Interface and class you use as mentioned above and use `[ComVisible(true)]`, but also note that using `[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(...))]` is unnecessary except in different circumstances: [Is there any purpose of ComDefaultInterface for a COM Callable Wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351840/is-there-any-purpose-of-comdefaultinterface-for-a-com-callable-wrapper#19351914).

The following is the correct syntax:

```
[Guid(...)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ITestClass
{
    [DispId(1)]
    string TestMethod();
}

[Guid(...)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    public string TestMethod()
    {
        return "Version 2-PROD Version";
    }
    public TestClass() : base() { }
}
```

This will prevent unintended behaviors. You also need a parameterless contructor and you might as well explicitly inherit from System.Object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182203.aspx

Syntax changed a little bit since the answer marked correct.