# Is there any purpose of ComDefaultInterface for a COM Callable Wrapper?

Tags: c#, .net, com, marshalling, com-interop

What is the purpose of [ComDefaultInterfaceAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comdefaultinterfaceattribute.aspx) attribute, if the managed object with `ClassInterfaceType.None` [is marshaled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comdefaultinterfaceattribute.aspx) as either `IUnknown` or `IDispatch`, anyway?

Consider the following C# class `AuthenticateHelper`, which implements COM `IAuthenticate`:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("79eac9d0-baf9-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IAuthenticate
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int Authenticate(
        [In, Out] ref IntPtr phwnd,
        [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] ref string pszUsername,
        [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] ref string pszPassword);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IAuthenticate))]
public class AuthenticateHelper: IAuthenticate
{
    public int Authenticate(ref IntPtr phwnd, ref string pszUsername, ref string pszPassword)
    {
        phwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        pszUsername = String.Empty;
        pszPassword = String.Empty;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I've just learnt that .NET interop runtime separates its implementation of `IUnknown` from `IAuthenticate` for such class:

```
AuthenticateHelper ah = new AuthenticateHelper();
IntPtr unk1 = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(ah, typeof(IAuthenticate));
IntPtr unk2 = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(ah);
Debug.Assert(unk1 == unk2); // will assert!
```

I've learn that while implementing `IServiceProvder`, because **the following did not work**, it was crashing inside the client code upon returning from `QueryService`:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IServiceProvider
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int QueryService(
        [In] ref Guid guidService,
        [In] ref Guid riid,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface, IidParameterIndex=1)] out object ppvObject    
}

// ...

public readonly Guid IID_IUnknown = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");

AuthenticateHelper ah = new AuthenticateHelper();

int IServiceProvider.QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out object ppvObject)
{
    if (guidService == typeof(IAuthenticate).GUID && (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == guidService))
    {
        ppvObject = this.ah; // same as ppvObject = (IAuthenticate)this.ah
        return S_OK;
    }
    ppvObject = null;
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}
```

I naively expected the instance of `AuthenticateHelper` would be marshaled as `IAuthenticate` because the class declares `[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IAuthenticate))]`, so **`IAuthenticate` is the only and the default COM interface** implemented by this class. However, that did not work, obviously because the object still gets marshaled as `IUnknown`.

**The following works**, but it changes the signature of `QueryService` and makes it less friendly for consuming (rather than providing) objects:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IServiceProvider
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int QueryService(
        [In] ref Guid guidService,
        [In] ref Guid riid,
        [Out] out IntPtr ppvObject);
}

// ...

int IServiceProvider.QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject)
{
    if (guidService == typeof(IAuthenticate).GUID && (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == guidService))
    {
        ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this.ah, typeof(IAuthenticate));
        return S_OK;
    }
    ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero;
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}
```

So, why would I specify `ComDefaultInterface` at all, if it doesn't affect marshaling? The only other use I see is for type library generation.

It's unmanaged client COM code that calls my managed implementation of `IServiceProvider::QueryService`. Is there a way to make `QueryService` work in my example without resorting to low-level stuff like `GetComInterfaceForObject`?

Comment: Yes, just the type library, it sets the [default] attribute on one of the interfaces listed in the coclass.  Helps a compiler of a language that doesn't support interfaces to figure out what interface to ask for when the object gets created, VB6 being the standard example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ComDefaultInterface` attribute is only really useful if you have more than one interface implemented on a single object. The "first" interface exposed by an object can be important in certain cases, but the order is not actually specified by the language. The attribute forces the interface you specify to be emitted first, with any others coming in a non-specified order.

It is also meant for classes that you are exporting from managed code to COM, so that clients who get your class returned to them in ways other than `CoCreateObject` get the correct 'default' interface (e.g. if your class is marked as `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]`).

For imported classes that you work with via managed code, or classes that only implement a single interface, the attribute is harmless but essentially useless.

Also, as far as your last question, you rarely have to resort to low-level interface querying when using COM objects in fully managed code. The C# compiler will automatically handle the `QueryInterface` calls if you use the normal `as` and `is` type coercion keywords.  In your case, `AuthenticationHelper` is being created as a managed `AuthenticationHelper` class because that's what you asked for; if you know what interface you want and you know it's implemented, ask for that:

```
AuthenticateHelper ah = new AuthenticateHelper();
IAuthenticate ia = ah as IAuthenticate;
```

Comment: So, I'd disagree with the following statement, if I understood it correctly: *It is also meant for classes that you are exporting from managed code to COM, so that clients who get your class returned to them in ways other than `CoCreateObject` get the correct 'default' interface (e.g. if your class is marked as `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]`)*. Apparently, this doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing wrong there; I have never implemented `IServiceProvider` so I don't know why `QueryService` would be any different than, say, `QueryInterface`, but I can tell you that `ComDefaultInterface` is meaningless on a class with only one interface.

Comment: I thought that `ComDefaultInterface` would specify how a managed class is marshaled to an unmanaged client by default. By that I mean outgoing marshaling as generic `object`, i.e. `[Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object result` signature, like `QueryInterface`. That did not work for me. Are you saying it's still possible, without `Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject/Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject/Marshal.QueryInterface`?